# How do I use strongly typed models and @model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC. I have a service folder where I have a class which reads data from an XML file. I've created a controller that I think (?) should work, and I'm attempting to create a view for this as well but for some reason I can't get intellisense to autocomplete the @model which makes me think I've done something wrong. Additionally, when I try access model properties from the view (eg `Model.Description` - if that is even the syntax?) I get numerous missing { and } errors. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    NewsReader newsReader = new NewsReader(); //Read news from file
    var newsItems = newsReader.GetNewsItems();

    return View(newsItems);
}
```

And so far this is all I have for the view:

```
@Model IEnumerable<TestSite.Services.News.NewsItem>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach(Model.Description)
            {

            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using a `foreach` loop it would need to be `foreach(var item in Model) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description) }` but if this view is for editing properties of `NewsItem` then a `foreach` loop will not work. You need a `for` loop (the model must be `IList<NewsItem>`) or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `NewItem`. You need to show your models.

Comment: why is your Model in uppercase in declaration, should be @model

Answer (score 3):

Refer to @Erik Funkenbusch explanation of [MVC @model meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681414/mvc-model-meaning)

> The @ sign is a directive to tell the Razor engine that what follows
>   is code, and it should compile that rather than simply write it to the
>   output.
>
> so when you type
>
> @model blah This is compiled by razor, and tells the Razor engine that
>   the type of the model is 'blah', so that when you use the keyword
>   Model (note the capital M and you would have to use the @ sign as
>   well) it will refer to the model you have defined (in this case blah).

Therefore corrections should be taken as following:

```
//@Model IEnumerable<TestSite.Services.News.NewsItem>
@model IEnumerable<TestSite.Services.News.NewsItem>


//@foreach(Model.Description)
@foreach(var item in model.Description)
{
}
```

I recommend you to read [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) to learn some basics about ASP.NET MVC 5. Razor engine is used by MVC 5 for the view styling.

[And have some idea here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)